# Drag and drop Multiple file upload to single file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to use a drag and drop in my website.I tried using many scripts and finally i found one in codpen. But here its possible to upload multiple files i only need to upload a single file that too pdf or .doc. How can i rewrite it or some one tell me how it is working. so that i can customise accordingly.

```
    "use strict";

//DOM
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

//APP
var App = {};
App.init = function () {
    //Init
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        //files template
        var template = "" + Object.keys(files).map(function (file) {
            return "<div class=\"file file--" + file + "\">\n     <div class=\"name\"><span>" + files[file].name + "</span></div>\n     <div class=\"progress active\"></div>\n     <div class=\"done\">\n\t<a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\">\n      <svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" version=\"1.1\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\">\n\t\t<g><path id=\"path\" d=\"M500,10C229.4,10,10,229.4,10,500c0,270.6,219.4,490,490,490c270.6,0,490-219.4,490-490C990,229.4,770.6,10,500,10z M500,967.7C241.7,967.7,32.3,758.3,32.3,500C32.3,241.7,241.7,32.3,500,32.3c258.3,0,467.7,209.4,467.7,467.7C967.7,758.3,758.3,967.7,500,967.7z M748.4,325L448,623.1L301.6,477.9c-4.4-4.3-11.4-4.3-15.8,0c-4.4,4.3-4.4,11.3,0,15.6l151.2,150c0.5,1.3,1.4,2.6,2.5,3.7c4.4,4.3,11.4,4.3,15.8,0l308.9-306.5c4.4-4.3,4.4-11.3,0-15.6C759.8,320.7,752.7,320.7,748.4,325z\"</g>\n\t\t</svg>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</a>\n     </div>\n    </div>";
        }).join("");

        $("#drop").classList.add("hidden");
        $("footer").classList.add("hasFiles");
        $(".importar").classList.add("active");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".list-files").innerHTML = template;
        }, 1000);

        Object.keys(files).forEach(function (file) {
            var load = 2000 + file * 2000; // fake load
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".file--" + file).querySelector(".progress").classList.remove("active");
                $(".file--" + file).querySelector(".done").classList.add("anim");
            }, load);
        });
    }

    // trigger input
    $("#triggerFile").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("input[type=file]").click();
    });

    // drop events
    $("#drop").ondragleave = function (evt) {
        $("#drop").classList.remove("active");
        evt.preventDefault();
    };
    $("#drop").ondragover = $("#drop").ondragenter = function (evt) {
        $("#drop").classList.add("active");
        evt.preventDefault();
    };
    $("#drop").ondrop = function (evt) {
        $("input[type=file]").files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
        $("footer").classList.add("hasFiles");
        $("#drop").classList.remove("active");
        evt.preventDefault();
    };

    //upload more
    $(".importar").addEventListener("click", function () {
        $(".list-files").innerHTML = "";
        $("footer").classList.remove("hasFiles");
        $(".importar").classList.remove("active");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#drop").classList.remove("hidden");
        }, 500);
    });

    // input change
    $("input[type=file]").addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect);
}();
```

link to codepen : https://codepen.io/jotavejv/pen/bRdaVJ

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Its good to understand how codes work. But if you are looking for file uploads, there are good jquery multifile upload plugins available on the internet and which is being used by a lot of developers. Search for Plupload (http://www.plupload.com/) (I use this most of the time), https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/. I recommend to use this as they will have there built in events which we can use for customization

Answer (score 0):

Source code on codepen using `multiple`. If you want to upload only one file for each time. Should you remove `multiple`

Example:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

Should you change to:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Hope help your problems.

Comment: I knew this but its showing many files on uplaod.I mean the layout. It makes users confused .So how can i give an error. Even an alert is fine i can do the rest.